# What does "punch of salt" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-brasco

In Donnie Brasco (1997), Lefty & Pistone argue about salt in the kitchen:

What does "punch of salt" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It doesn't mean anything

It's a mispronunciation of "pinch of salt", that is clear from the dialogue.